# How to match strings anywhere in R?

Tags: r

I have an object called

```
 fruits<-c("apple","banana","pineapple","mango")
```

and I have object called

```
 wanted.string<-c("app","ana")
```

I want to match the strings in `wanted.string` with the string in fruits(so match anywhere in those strings) and get the matched results, i.e.

```
 apple, banana, pineapple
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#Paste everything together into a large OR statement
wnt <- paste0(wanted.string, collapse="|")
#Then see if any match
grep(wnt, fruits, value=TRUE)

## [1] "apple"     "banana"    "pineapple"
```

Answer (score 4):

Another option is `str_detect` from `stringr` which is vectorized over 'string' and 'pattern'.  We get a logical vector with `str_detect` that can be used for subsetting the original vector.

```
 library(stringr)
 fruits[str_detect(fruits, wanted.string)]
 #[1] "apple"     "banana"    "pineapple"
```

Answer (score 2):

You `grep` with `sapply`:

```
unlist(sapply(wanted.string, function(ii) grep(ii, fruits, value=TRUE)))
#       app1        app2         ana 
#    "apple" "pineapple"    "banana"
```

Comment: I'm not sure the first solution works. Try it with `fruits<-c("apple","appo","pineapple","mango")` and it fails. The second seems to work fine, though.

Comment: @N8TRO Even with my suggested string? It seems that mapply checks the first with the first, second with second, first with third, etc. So it only applies the criteria alternately. Hence it works for the example, but not for mine.